# using CSS to show subclass on mouse hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to show a div by its subclass name on hover using CSS but can't seem to work properly. When the user hovers over `hover_group`'s `myhover` class, the hidden_info should display.

I've tried using `+` or `~` CSS selectors as well but it doesn't seem to function..what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <style>

        .hidden_info {
            display:none;
        }

        .hover_group .myhover:hover{
            background-color: yellow;

            //.hidden_info {
              //  background-color: red;
                //display:block;
            //}
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>

<div class="hover_group">
    <ul>
        <li class="myhover">
            <div class="myhover">hover here!</div>
            <div class="hidden_info">Hello world!</div>
        </li>
        <li class="myhover">
            <div class="myhover">hover here!</div>
            <div class="hidden_info">Hello world!</div>
        </li>
        <li class="myhover">
            <div class="myhover">hover here!</div>
            <div class="hidden_info">Hello world!</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same class for different elements (li and div). You then need to be more specific about which element to affect.

In this case I check for the hover on the div and the sibling will become visible. Hence the + used. If you want to validate the hover on the list item, the + must be removed because the div with class `.hidden` is not a sibling of the list item but a child element.

```css
.hidden_info {
  display: none;
}

div.myhover:hover+.hidden_info {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover_group">
  <ul>
    <li class="myhover">
      <div class="myhover">hover here!</div>
      <div class="hidden_info">Hello world!</div>
    </li>
    <li class="myhover">
      <div class="myhover">hover here!</div>
      <div class="hidden_info">Hello world!</div>
    </li>
    <li class="myhover">
      <div class="myhover">hover here!</div>
      <div class="hidden_info">Hello world!</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```